# Flutter : How to set datatype for each elements we want to upload to firebase database?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, types

I want to upload a bunch of data into firebase database and set those data into a specific datatype.
In firebase database, we have string, number, boolean, map, array, null, timestamp, geopoint, and reference.
How do I get my flutter code to specify my database elements' types.

```
Future database() async {
    return await userCollection.document(uid).setData({
      string : , 
      number : , 
      boolean : , 
      map : , 
      array : , 
      null : , 
      timestamp : , 
      geopoint : ,
      reference: ,
         });
}
```

Comment: Since the answer helped you please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[`setData`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_reference.dart#L88) takes a `map` as an argument, therefore you have to do the following:

```
Future database() async {
    return await userCollection.document(uid).setData(
  {
    "name" : "john",
    "age" : 50,
    "email" : "example@example.com",
    "address" : {
      "street" : "street 24",
      "city" : "new york"
    }
  })
```

This way you will add a string, integer, and a map to the database.